# chain rule conditional entropy

Tags: probability, machine-learning, entropy

I have to prove the chain-rule for conditional entropy. I kept getting stuck on one step, so I looked up a proof and found this: 
\begin{align}H(Y\mid X)&= \sum_{x\in\mathcal X, y\in\mathcal Y}p(x,y)\log \frac {p(x)} {p(x,y)}\tag{1}\\&= -\sum_{x\in\mathcal X, y\in\mathcal Y}p(x,y)\log\,p(x,y) + \sum_{x\in\mathcal X, y\in\mathcal Y}p(x,y)\log\,p(x) \tag{2}\\
&=  H(X,Y) + \sum_{x \in \mathcal X} p(x)\log\,p(x)\tag{3}\\
 &=  H(X,Y) - H(X)\tag{4}\end{align}

This is identical to the proof I had made on my own, but it makes a step that I didn't think was allowed. Specifically, can someone explain how you are able to move from the joint probability to the marginal probability between steps 2 and 3? It seems like I'm missing something basic and obvious, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is phrased as whether
$$
\sum_{x\in\mathcal X, y\in\mathcal Y}p(x,y)\log\,p(x) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal X} p(x)\log\,p(x) \quad \text{?}
$$

I disapprove of using the same symbol, $p$, for two different functions.  If one instead writes $p_X(x)$ with capital $X$ and lower-case $x$ in the appropriate places, one can then understand such things as the difference between $p_X(4)$ and $p_Y(4)$, and the meaning of $p_X(4)$, and things like $\Pr(X\le x)$.

We have
\begin{align}
& \sum_{\begin{smallmatrix} x\in\mathcal X \\ y\in\mathcal Y \end{smallmatrix}} \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) \log p(x) & & \text{where $p(x)$ is some function of $x$} \\[10pt]
= {} & \sum_{x\in\mathcal X} \left( \sum_{y\in\mathcal Y} \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) \log p(x) \right) & & \text{where $p(x)$ is some function of $x$.}
\end{align}

The factor $\log p(x)$ within the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y}$ does not depend on $y$, i.e. it does not change as $y$ runs through the list of all members of $\mathcal Y$.  Therefore we can pull it out, getting this:
$$
\sum_{x\in\mathcal X} \left( (\log p(x)) \sum_{y\in\mathcal Y} \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) \right)
$$
Now all we need to do is show that
$$
\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y} \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y) = \Pr(X=x).
$$
For example, if $\mathcal Y=\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$, we would need to show that
$$
\Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y_1) + \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y_2) + \Pr(X=x\ \&\ Y=y_3) = \Pr(X=x).
$$
Can you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply because
$$
\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y}p(x,y)=  p(x).
$$
Really, you had done all difficult work already.

Comment: I realize now that I did essentially that in another proof in the assignment. Just so I'm sure, there's no problem in saying:  \begin{align}&=\sum_{j=1}^{m}q_j\big(-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(P=i)\log\mathbb{P}(P=i)\big)\tag{$P\independent Q$)}\\&=\big(\sum_{j=1}^{m}q_j\big)\cdot\big(-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(P=i)\log\mathbb{P}(P=i)\big)\tag{factoring}\\&=\big(1\big)\cdot\big(-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(P=i)\log\mathbb{P}(P=i)\big)\tag{By definition, all $q_j$'s sum to 1}\end{align}